# Camel AdviceWith not replacing an endpoint with a specified file

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm quite new to Camel and despite having read the Apache Camel documentation, I'm stuck on what I hope is a trivial issue which I've overlooked.

I have a Spring Boot application that defines a Camel route which consumes live prices in csv format from an HTTP call, converts the CSV to a POJO (LivePrice) using Bindy, then persists the data to a store.

Here's the route definition:

```java
@Component
public class LivePricesCSVRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("kafka:" + "{{kafka.topic.live.prices.csv}}" + "{{kafka.broker.location}}")
                .routeId("live.prices-persistence-route")
                .transacted()
                .unmarshal()
                .bindy(BindyType.Csv, LivePrice.class).id("convertToCsv")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    List<LivePrice> object = (List<LivePrice>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
                    object.remove(0); // omit the header
                    logger.info(object);
                })
        .bean("livePriceServiceImpl", "populateLivePrices").id("populateLivePrices");
    }
}
```

I want to create an integration test for this route where I supply a test csv file containing two lines and a header as an input rather than expecting messages on the topic kafka.topic.live.prices.csv.

```
Date,Symbol,Open,
2019-07-09,BTCUSD,12347.18
2019-07-08,BTCUSD,11475.07
```

I also want to intercept the Exchange before it is persisted and send it to the endpoint mock:output where I can perform assertions.

Here's the test I've written:

```java
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class LivePricesPersistenceRouteTest {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output")
    private MockEndpoint mockOutput;

    @Test
    public void testSendLivePricesCsvToTopic() throws Exception {

        camelContext.getRouteDefinition("live-prices-persistence-route")
                .adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        replaceFromWith("file://testCsvFile.csv");                      
                        intercept()
                                .to("mock:output");
                    }
                });

      camelContext.start();

      Exchange exchange = mockOutput.assertExchangeReceived(0);
      List<LivePrice> livePrices = (List<LivePrice>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
      assertThat(livePrices.get(0).getDate(), is("2019-07-09"));        
      // TODO ADD MORE ASSERTIONS
      mockOutput.assertIsSatisfied();

    }
}
```

When I run the test, the following is logged by Camel:

```xml
2019-07-13 14:35:16.587  INFO 90356 --- [           main] org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition   : Adviced route before/after as XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="live-prices-persistence-route">
    <from uri="kafka:{{kafka.topic.live.prices.csv}}{{kafka.broker.location}}"/>
    <transacted>
        <unmarshal customId="true" id="convertToCsv">
            <bindy type="Csv"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <process/>
        <bean customId="true" id="populateLivePrices" method="populateLivePrices" ref="livePriceServiceImpl"/>
    </transacted>
</route>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="live-prices-persistence-route">
    <from uri="file://testCsvFile.csv"/>
    <intercept>
        <to uri="mock:output"/>
    </intercept>
    <transacted>
        <unmarshal customId="true" id="convertToCsv">
            <bindy type="Csv"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <process/>
        <bean customId="true" id="populateLivePrices" method="populateLivePrices" ref="livePriceServiceImpl"/>
    </transacted>
</route>
```

However the test fails with the following output:

```java
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://output Not enough messages received. Was: 0
at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.fail(MockEndpoint.java:1494)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertTrue(MockEndpoint.java:1482)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint.assertExchangeReceived(MockEndpoint.java:1078)
    at com.xxx.liveprices.routes.LivePricesPersistenceRouteTest.testSendLivePricesCsvToTopic(LivePricesPersistenceRouteTest.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Can anyone please guide me as to why the file isn't being used and why the Exchange isn't being intercepted and sent to the mock endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

After much more reading, I was still **unable** to determine why the following code didn't read and swap out my input data:

```
replaceFromWith("file://testCsvFile.csv");
```

I opted instead for supplying the CSV file's contents as a String and using **weaveById** to replace the input data.

Here's the test with my objective accomplished:

```java
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class LivePricesPersistenceRouteTest {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:output")
    private MockEndpoint mockOutput;

    @Test
    public void testSendLivePricesCsvToTopic() throws Exception {

        camelContext.getRouteDefinition("live-prices-persistence-route")
                .adviceWith(camelContext, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        replaceFromWith("direct:test");
                        weaveById("populateLivePrices").replace().inOut("mock:output");

                    }
                });

        camelContext.start();

        String message = "Date,Symbol,Open,\n" +
                "2019-07-09,BTCUSD,12347.18\n" +
                "2019-07-08,BTCUSD,11475.07";

        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:test", message);

        Exchange exchange = mockOutput.assertExchangeReceived(0);
        List<LivePrice> livePrices = (List<LivePrice>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
        assertThat(livePrices.get(0).getDate(), is("2019-07-09"));
        assertThat(livePrices.get(0).getOpen(), is("12347.18"));

        assertThat(livePrices.get(1).getDate(), is("2019-07-08"));
        assertThat(livePrices.get(1).getOpen(), is("11475.07"));

        mockOutput.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but in case anyone else runs into the same issue...

I looked at the implementation of `MockEndpoint.assertExchangeReceived()`. This method does NOT have any wait mechanism built in, unlike `MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()`, which will wait for a configurable amount of time to receive the expected number of exchanges (configurable via `resultWaitTime`). The microsecond it takes to go from `camelContext.start()` to `mockOutput.assertExchangeReceived(0)` is clearly not enough for Camel to process your input file.

You almost got it right but the position of `assertIsSatisfied()` is too late and an actual expectation is missing. Here is what I think should work:

```java
      mockOutput.expectedMessageCount(1);
      camelContext.start();

      mockOutput.assertIsSatisfied();
      // if the statement above passes, the endpoint is guaranteed
      // to have received at least one exchange
      Exchange exchange = mockOutput.assertExchangeReceived(0);
      List<LivePrice> livePrices = (List<LivePrice>)exchange.getIn().getBody();
      assertThat(livePrices.get(0).getDate(), is("2019-07-09"));        
      // TODO ADD MORE ASSERTIONS
```